# Laravel 5.1 Maintenance Mode Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware, maintenance-mode

Hi I am trying to put my Laravel 5.1 app into maintenance mode using the `php artisan down` command but it is not showing a maintenance page the app continues to function the same.

I can confirm that the `down` file is being created in `storage/app/framework` directory and my kernel has the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class` in the global $`middleware` array.

I have also tried changing the .env APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG values with no success.

If anyone can help me identify why maintenance mode isn't working it would be much appreciated.

Comment: For enable maintenance mode it's need to generate a file in storage folder.May it's haven't permission to create file,so please try to give permission in storage folder.

Comment: As I stated in my question it is creating the 'down' file correctly and removing it using the php artisan up command.

Comment: that was my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Let me clear all the things----------

1. You launch app by `php artisan serve`

1.1 To put in maintenance mode:

`php artisan down`

then

`php artisan serve`

1.2 To put in live mode:

`php artisan up`

then

`php artisan serve`